# Exponent of group with order power of two

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Considering the multiplicative group of integers modulo $2^k, k \geq 3$, it can be [proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Proof_for_Powers_of_Two) that the exponent of the group is a divisor of $2^{k-2}$.

How can it be proved that there will always exist an element with order equal to $2^{k-2}$ and not to a divisor of it (the exponent of such a group is $2^{k-2}$)?

Comment: You prove it by showing that $5$ has mulitiplicative order $2^{k-2}$ mod $2^k$.

Comment: The way to prove that involves showing that $5^{2^{k-2}} = 1 + (2n+1) \cdot 2^k$? And how is 5 chosen?

Comment: The easiest way is to expand $(1+4)^{2^{k-2}}$ using the binomial theorem.

Comment: So we need to prove that $2^k \mid $ ${{2^{k-2}}}\choose{i}$ $\cdot 4^i, i \geq 1$? And because $2^{k+1} \nmid$ ${2^{k-2}}\choose{1}$ $\cdot 4^1$, the order is exactly $2^{k-2}$?

Comment: One way would still be to prove that $5^{2^{k-2}} = 1 + (2n+1) \cdot 2^k$ by induction. The base case is $(1+4)^{2^{3-2}} = 1+(2\cdot 1 + 1)\cdot 8$. So if $(1+4)^{2^{k-2}} = 1+(2\cdot n + 1)\cdot 2^k$, then $(1+4)^{2^{k-1}} = (1+(2\cdot n + 1)\cdot 2^k)^2 = 1+ (2\cdot n + 1 + (2 \cdot n + 1)^2 \cdot 2^{k-1}) \cdot 2^{k+1}$. And $(2\cdot n + 1 + (2 \cdot n + 1)^2 \cdot 2^{k-1})$ is again odd. Could you show me the proof involving the binomial expansion of $(1+4)^{2^{k-2}}$?

Comment: You are proving the wrong thing. You said in your post that you already know that the exponent of the group divides $2^{k-2}$, so you don't need to prove that again. What you need to prove is that $5^{2^{k-3}}$ is *not*  congruent to $1$ modulo $2^k$. It is not difficult.

Comment: I am sorry for insisting, but with the above I tried to prove that $5^{2^{k-3}} \equiv 1+2^{k-1} (mod \space 2^k)$ (I think this is correct, so the proof is over). Using the binomial expansion, I keep arriving at the step where I need to prove that $2^k \mid $ ${{2^{k-2}}}\choose{i}$, $i \geq 2$. The first two terms being $1 + 2^{k-1}$, the result when taken modulo $2^k$. Again, I apologize for insisting.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the $4^i$ term. And I think you mean $\binom{2^{k-3}}{i}$. Sorry but that's my last comment on this!